# Representing prepositions in lambda calculus/logic notation

Tags: semantics, computational-linguistics, lambda-calculus

How would I represent 'for' in "Are you here for a conference?"

1. conference could be represented as `lam x.conference(x)`.
2. a conference could be represented as `lam Q x.(conference(x) & Q(x))`

I assume that I know the meaning of `for` in this context. (Prepositions are polysemous)

Comment: "Are" is not a preposition: it is a verb. Most prepositions have their own semantics, and would need to be represented by their own operations in any logical form. Some are merely syntactic sugar (some uses of _of_, for example).

Comment: I'd use "P" for preposition.  (But I doubt the question you ask is really meaningful.)

Comment: "For the conference" is a preposition phrase @ColinFine. I provided a complete sentence as an example.

Comment: @GregLee I do not think you understood my question. Perhaps my edited version is clearer.

Comment: Lambdas provide a way to express functional abstraction.  What does this have to do your question about representing "for"?  I just don't see any connection.

Comment: Yeah nice question. Did you try to google it? I know semanticists often work around this by glossing over the structure of the predicate (*come-for-a-conference*(x)) when they're interested in other things. But I would think that someone looked into this before?

Comment: @IvanKapitonov Yes, I tried googling it. I asked here because nothing addressed my question. There are works with titles like "the Semantics of Prepositions". They discuss sense relations and pragmatics. The sections on computational semantics said some version of "not much known here".

Comment: Ok, I see. Well, then do you find my suggestion helpful at all? I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

Just from this example it would seem that the type of *for* is `((e,t),t), ((e,t),(e,t))` -- because it combines with a DP to make up an adjunct to the VP. Thus, it could have a semantics like the following (I'm just making it up)

(1) [[for]] = λP<sub>et,t</sub>λQ<sub>et</sub>λx<sub>e</sub>(Q(x) for(P))

Indeed I should sit down and think if it makes any sense :-) But I hope this helps -- I'll be interested to hear what you think.

Comment: Why did you use 'because-of' instead of 'for' in (1)?  (If you use 'for', then we can conclude that we can use '[[for]]' when we can use 'for'.)

Comment: @GregLee: Nothing particular, just was trying to interpret 'for'. Sure, I've changed it to `for`.